# Validation group mat-cheeckbox in reactive form

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

Is it possible to validate a group of mat-checkbox?

I want at least one box to be selectable.

[image]

I have this:

ts:

```
this.formSalud = this.fb.group({
      categorias: this.fb.group({
        internacional: [false],
        nacional: [false],
        nacionalSinReembolso: [false],
        nacionalClinicasAcotadas: [false]
      }, requireCheckboxesToBeCheckedValidator()),
    });
```

html:

```
 <div class="d-flex flex-column" formGroupName="categorias">
     <mat-checkbox formControlName="internacional" id="internacional">Internacional</mat-checkbox>
     <mat-checkbox formControlName="nacional">Nacional</mat-checkbox>
     <mat-checkbox formControlName="nacionalSinReembolso">Nacional sin reembolso</mat-checkbox>
     <mat-checkbox formControlName="nacionalClinicasAcotadas">Nacional con clínicas acotadas</mat-checkbox>                     
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Comment: Yes: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kbleng?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

Your valdiator call is wrong. It should look like this:

```
this.formSalud = this.fb.group({
      categorias: this.fb.group({
        internacional: [false],
        nacional: [false],
        nacionalSinReembolso: [false],
        nacionalClinicasAcotadas: [false]
      }, { validators:[ requireCheckboxesToBeCheckedValidator]}),
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Angular [custom validators](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators) to achieve this.

```
this.formSalud = this.fb.group({
    internacional: [false],
    nacional: [false],
    nacionalSinReembolso: [false],
    nacionalClinicasAcotadas: [false]
  }, { validators: requireCheckboxesToBeCheckedValidator });

export const requireCheckboxesToBeCheckedValidator: ValidatorFn = (control: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null => {
 const nacional = control.get('nacional').value;
 const internacional = control.get('internacional').value;
 const nacionalSinReembolso = control.get('nacionalSinReembolso').value;
 const nacionalClinicasAcotadas = control.get('nacionalClinicasAcotadas').value;

 const isAnyChecked = nacional || internacional || nacionalSinReembolso || nacionalClinicasAcotadas

 return isAnyChecked ? null : { required: true };
};
```

In template show errors

```
<div *ngIf="formSalud.errors?.required">Check at least one checkbox.</div>
```

Comment: And how do I show the error? I am trying the following: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kbleng?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: @PacoZevallos few glitches I saw in your code why you are adding form group inside form group? and the `v` of `validators` is small you were using capital in your example. I forked your stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-33vhjw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html checkout now

Comment: @PacoZevallos does that work for you, if yes dont forget to accept the answer which will help other colleagues

Answer (score 0):

**Issue1:**
In your formGroup you have typo It should be validators.

**component.ts**

```
this.formSalud = this.fb.group({
      categorias: this.fb.group({
        internacional: [false],
        nacional: [false],
        nacionalSinReembolso: [false],
        nacionalClinicasAcotadas: [false]
      }, { validators: requireCheckboxesToBeCheckedValidator }),
    });
```

**Issue2:** Since customValidator returns Error Object key as required you need to replace required instead of isAnyChecked

**component.html**

```
 <form [formGroup]="formSalud" novalidate class="pt-3 pt-md-4">
  <div class="col-12">
      <div class="d-flex flex-column" formGroupName="categorias">
          <mat-checkbox formControlName="internacional">Internacional</mat-checkbox>
          <mat-checkbox formControlName="nacional">Nacional</mat-checkbox>
          <mat-checkbox formControlName="nacionalSinReembolso">Nacional sin reembolso</mat-checkbox>
          <mat-checkbox formControlName="nacionalClinicasAcotadas">Nacional con clínicas acotadas</mat-checkbox>
          <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="formSalud.controls['categorias'].errors && formSalud.controls['categorias'].errors.required">Se requiere marcar al menos una casilla.</div>
      </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Issue3:** When using bootstrap invalid-feedback. It set the element display property to none override this with following css in your component.

**component.css**

```
.invalid-feedback{
  display: block;
}
```

[Check this For More Info](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/23454)

[Forked Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-q3z6n5?file=src/app/app.component.html)