# How should I apply conditional validation logic to a reactive form, based on the forms current values?

Tags: angular, forms

I have some code like this:

```
this.form.controls[keyOf<IBranchForm>('vatNo')].valueChanges
                .subscribe(change => {
                    this.setOrRemoveValidators(this.form);
                });

private setOrRemoveValidators(form: FormGroup): void {
    const vatNoIsRequired = true;
    if (vatNoIsRequired) {
        form.controls['vatNo'].setValidators(Validators.required);
    }
    else {
        form.controls['vatNo'].setValidators([]);
    }

    form.controls['vatNo'].updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

the problem I'm facing is that I need to update the form value and validity in order to add or remove the error displayed in the UI, but of course this causes the subscribe to run again, and we get into an infinite loop.

I now feel that the approach of changing a forms value or validity based on value changes is probably not the correct approach as it becomes messy with hacks to get around the issues (emitEvent: false will also not cause UI updates).

So what is the correct way to approach this problem please?

Comment: You might want to use custom validators. Have in mind that even though validator receives AbstractControl to which it's attached, so in theory you could check the values of other fields, validites are updated only on value changes. So you might be better off writing a custom validator on FormGroup level. In the validator, you can use getErrors on field, change the object if needed and use setErrors using the modified object. This way validations will fire on any change on the form.

Comment: or you could `updateValueAndValidity({emitEvent: false})`. there are still situations where you want to apply validators only in some cases

Comment: This should answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63885722/validation-group-mat-cheeckbox-in-reactive-form/63886984#63886984